# Update with conditional Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm updating a value inside an array. But, I want that the update validates that the value cannot be less than zero.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  items: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId(),
        stock: 5
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, if I want to decrease stock in -6. I need that the query raise an exception or something similar.

I was trying with two queries. One to know the actual value and then if the subtraction was > 0, I did the update.

Is there a way to make this in one query?

Comment: Why not check the condition in the select statement: var value=100; db.users.update({
    "name" : "xyz",
    "score" : { "$gt" : value }
},
{
    $set : { "score" : value}
})

Comment: For that, I need to know the index of the document in the array. How can I get it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `ObjectId` is unique in for each element in the array and use the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional update operator to do this beautifully

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

collection.update_one(
    {"items": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58ccc8c2dbe8051261b38e58"), 
            "stock": {"$gt": 0 }
        }
    }}, 
    {"$inc": {"items.$.stock": -6 }}
)
```